# Remove/adjust the title of FixMe Annotations

Tags: fixme

I have a short question - how is it possible to remove or adjust the title of a Fixme Annotation. I've alread tried something like that:

```
\renewcommand*\FXLayoutMargin[3]{%
{\@fxuseface{margin}\ignorespaces[#3 \fxnotename{#1}: #2]}}
```

But if I remove the #3 or #2 variable the latex build process interrupts.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[status=draft]{fixme}
\fxsetface{margin}{\tiny}

\begin{document}
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
\fxnote{Im the content - i dont like the title}
 Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

Here is the wanted output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still want some title the logo and the Note text can be changed (if the language is set to English):

```
\renewcommand\fixmelogo{\textsf{MyLogo}}
\renewcommand\fxenglishnotename{MyNoteName}
```

Even though it is possible to set both to `{}` it really doesn't help if you want to get rid of the title completely since there is a `:` in the definition.

I am not sure we have the same versions of the sty-file since the definition of `\FXLayoutMargin` in mine is not the same as you specify. There are three inputs, where the `#1` is the note name, `#2` the note text and `#3` the logo. So you should not remove `#2`. In your version try to remove `#3 \fxnotename{#1}:`. Since you are messing with internal commands you need to put `\makeatletter` before and `\makeatother` after. In my version I included the following before `\begin{document}`.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\FXLayoutMargin[3]{%
  \marginpar[%
  %\raggedleft\@fxuseface{margin}\ignorespaces#3 \fxnotename{#1}: #2]{%
  \raggedleft\@fxuseface{margin} #2]{%
    %\raggedright\@fxuseface{margin}\ignorespaces#3 \fxnotename{#1}: #2}}
    \raggedright\@fxuseface{margin} #2}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the additional information and your solution - this works very well!

Answer (score 3):

As a possible alternative to StefanH's solution, you may use:

`\fxsetup{theme=color}` (= the difference between the various kind of notes: `fxnote`, `fxwarning`, `fxerror`, `fxfatal` is the color, without the explicit name "Note", etc.)

together with:

`author=` (= FiXme is not inserted)

options of `fixme` package.

If you don't like the colored notes, you may define their colors in this way:

```
\definecolor{fxnote}{rgb}{0.0000,0.0000,0.0000}
\definecolor{fxwarning}{rgb}{0.0000,0.0000,0.0000}
\definecolor{fxerror}{rgb}{0.0000,0.0000,0.0000}
\definecolor{fxfatal}{rgb}{0.0000,0.0000,0.0000}
```

(these lines are commented in the MWE).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[status=draft,author=]{fixme}
\fxsetup{theme=color}
\fxsetface{margin}{\tiny}
%\definecolor{fxnote}{rgb}{0.0000,0.0000,0.0000}
%\definecolor{fxwarning}{rgb}{0.0000,0.0000,0.0000}
%\definecolor{fxerror}{rgb}{0.0000,0.0000,0.0000}
%\definecolor{fxfatal}{rgb}{0.0000,0.0000,0.0000}

\begin{document}
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
\fxnote{Im the content - i dont like the title}
 Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

[image]